# Mouse shortcut to copy the path to a file in the Gnome file manager

Tags: filenames, nautilus, clipboard

Is there a Linux equivalent of the Windows Shift+Right-click sequence?  I use this a lot on files and directories to get the 'hidden' "Copy as path" option in the pop-up menu.  It saves a lot of typing (and typos) when using the command line.

I'm hoping that Linux has something similar, so I can go to the 'Files' window in a GUI (Gnome3 in my case) and just copy a file or directory location as a path and then paste it in a terminal window.  This function would be especially handy in Linux given the heavy reliance on the terminal!  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question to be honest, but I do know that shells have tab completion, so that you can easily avoid typos. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you click 'Copy' from the right-click context menu in Nautilus (file manager in GNOME3) and paste the contents in a text field (text editor, text box, etc.), it will paste the path instead of the file itself.

Comment: Works with Thunar (Xfce's file manager), too.

Comment: Also works with `nemo` (Cinnamon's file manager).

Comment: Works for me - thanks.  Very obvious when you think about it, although coming from Windows that approach would try to copy the entire file or just do nothing if you tried to paste into a command-line/shell.

Comment: @terdon nemo copies it as a `file://` path, which means the encoding doesn't use bash escape

Comment: it doesnt just paste the `path` of the file. it pastes additional information. my case:
```x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/alexzander/Documents/preparing_for_linux.py``` and its not helpful at all when you want to paste the path into a python variable for example.

Comment: Also works if using Control+C, not just from the context menu

Comment: Doesn't paste into Chrome's JS console. Just FYI sanity check.